# Как получить расстояние между курсором и объектом в Unity?

Tags: c#, unity3d

У меня есть метод, с помощью которого можно передвигать объект по клеточному полю (как в шахматах) (выравнивание объекта происходит по центру клеток, то есть оказаться на пересечении клеток он не может).

```
void Update()
{
    if (!dragging) return;
    var mouse = Input.mousePosition;
    var castPoint = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(mouse);
    if (!Physics.Raycast(castPoint, out var hit, Mathf.Infinity)) return;
    transform.position = hit.transform.position;
}
```

Если сейчас передвигать объект в пределах клеточного поля, все будет работать, так как `Physics.Raycast` будет находить клетку на своем пути и на ее координаты ставить фиолетовый кубик. Но если при перемещении кубика курсор уйдет за поле (как на фото 1) и будет перемещаться вне поля, координаты кубика не будут изменяться, так как `Physics.Raycast` не будет находить на своем пути клетки (2 фото). Если курсор вернуть на доску, то кубик мнгновенно переместиться на нужную клетку и продолжит нормальную работу (3 фото).

[image]

[image]

[image]

Мне нужно, чтобы при перемещении курсора вне поля искалась ближайшая клетка и кубик ставился на нее.
Сделал метод поиска ближайшей клетки относительно курсора и массив клеток. При попытке перемещения кубик встает на клетку в 3 ряду, 2 колонке и больше не двигается. Есть идеи, что именно не так?
P.S. 3 клетка в первой колонке имеет координаты (0, 0, 0) (колонки - по-вертикали).

```
private bool dragging;
    private GameObject[] tiles;

    void OnMouseDown()
    {
        dragging = true;
    }

    void OnMouseUp()
    {
        dragging = false;
    }

    void Start()
    {
        tiles = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Tile");
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (!dragging) return;
        var mouse = Input.mousePosition;
        var castPoint = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(mouse);
        if (!Physics.Raycast(castPoint, out _, Mathf.Infinity)) return;
        transform.position = GetNearest(mouse.normalized).transform.position;
    }

    private GameObject GetNearest(Vector3 position)
    {
        var nearestDist = float.MaxValue;
        GameObject nearest = null;
        foreach (var tile in tiles)
        {
            var dist = Vector3.Distance(position, tile.transform.position);
            if (dist < nearestDist)
            {
                nearestDist = dist;
                nearest = tile;
            }
        }
        return nearest;
    }
```

Comment: Рейкасть в плейнии узнаешь куда кликнул в независимости от наличия объекта https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Plane.Raycast.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Благодаря совету Yaroslav'а погуглил и нашел понятный пример кода:

```
var plane : Plane = new Plane(Vector3.up, Vector3.zero);;
 
function LateUpdate()
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
    {
        var ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
 
        var ent : float = 100.0;
        if (plane.Raycast(ray, ent))
        {
            Debug.Log("Plane Raycast hit at distance: " + ent);
            var hitPoint = ray.GetPoint(ent);
           
            var go = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Cube);
            go.transform.position = hitPoint;
            Debug.DrawRay (ray.origin, ray.direction * ent, Color.green);
        }
        else
            Debug.DrawRay (ray.origin, ray.direction * 10, Color.red);
    }
}
```

На нем видно, что такое `Panel`. Я его изменил под себя и теперь все работает.

```
if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
        {
            var ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);

            if (plane.Raycast(ray, out var ent))
            {
                var hitPoint = ray.GetPoint(ent);
                var nearest = GetNearest(hitPoint);
                transform.position = nearest.transform.position;
            }
        }
```

Еще нашел более короткий способ искать ближайший объект - можно список объектов сортировать по дистанции и брать первый:

```
var sorted = NearGameobjects.OrderBy(obj => (col.transform.position - transform.position).sqrMagnitude);
```

Но я пока не могу сказать, какой метод работает быстрее, если напишете, буду благодарен.

Comment: Можно просто округлить позицию до размера клетки и clamp x и y по размеру поля.

Comment: @Yaroslav не совсем понял, то есть можно искать кратчайшее расстояние к клетке округляя позицию кубика до размера клетки и с помощью clamp выравнивать кубик по центру? Если это так, то что значит округлить вектор? Взять проекцию?

Comment: Нет, если 0 0 левый нижний угол то индекс тайла находится Mathf.FloorToInt(hitPoint/tileSize). Clamp это про выход индекса за пределы доски.